What is the correct way of using FFT in LTspice for a non-periodic signals (simple pulse)
I fed a single pulse (amp=1 V, tr=1 µs, tf=1 µs, ton=100 µs, № of cycles=1), and I want to see its frequency spectrum using FFT option in LTspice.
I'm expecting a spectrum starting from 0 Hz with appropriate amplitude. But it starts from frequency depending on simulation time (1 ms ⇾ 1kHz, 10 ms ⇾ 100 Hz). The major difference I noticed is the amplitude in FFT varies with change in simulation time. Could someone help to understand this? How the amplitude in FFT varies with simulation time.
This variation is not observed for periodic signals.




You will want to include a repetitive square wave and give it at least a few cycles to work with. Also, make it an integer number of cycles as best you can. Otherwise, windowing becomes more of an issue. Also, center it around 0, without a DC offset. And if you want more accurate peaks (ones that better reflect the actual magnitude at each frequency then perhaps use the "flat top" window. It's a little better at that goal. Not much else to add.

Here's an example using a 100 Hz square wave centered on 0 V. I chose none for the windowing. It's about what you'd expect to see with odd order harmonics present.

@periblepsis Thanks for the reply. I would like to see the FFT spectrum for non-periodic signal (ex: pulse). In LT spice, it gives different magnitude for different simulation times. I need to understand and plot correctly.
